# Symfony 2 InvalidArgumentException: The file app/config/config_prod.yml does not exist

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to access a Symfony Installation on my VPS running CentOS.

The files /app/config/config_dev.yml and /app/config/config_prod_yml exist on the server. I even chmodded them to 0777 for testing purposes but I still get the error that they don't exists.

Full trace:

```
InvalidArgumentException: The file "/home/XXXXX/public_html/app/config/config_dev.yml" does not exist.

in /home/XXXXX/public_html/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 3637
at FileLocator->locate() in /home/XXXXX/public_html/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 4524
at FileLocator->locate() in /home/XXXXX/public_html/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php line 40
at YamlFileLoader->load() in /home/XXXXX/public_html/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Loader/DelegatingLoader.php line 52
at DelegatingLoader->load() in /home/XXXXX/public_html/app/AppKernel.php line 39
at AppKernel->registerContainerConfiguration() in /home/XXXXX/public_html/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 867
at Kernel->buildContainer() in /home/XXXXX/public_html/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 783
at Kernel->initializeContainer() in /home/XXXXX/public_html/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 517
at Kernel->boot() in /home/XXXXX/public_html/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 548
at Kernel->handle() in /home/XXXXX/public_html/web/app_dev.php line 28
```

Comment: what is output of this command: "ls -l /home/XXXXX/public_html/app/config/config_dev.yml" ?

Comment: @Cyprian -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 486 Oct  6 16:48 /home/XXXXX/public_html/app/config/config_dev.yml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a CHMOD issue where PHP didn't have access to the symfony core files.

Comment: I had to chown the public folder to the user that was running apache